# XML declaration with "FOR XML PATH" in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, for-xml-path

Below is a simplified version of a query that I have already created.  The query works fine, but I cannot figure out how to get the XML declaration at the top of the generated XML.  I've tried multiple things and searched far and wide on the Google, but alas I cannot seem to find out how to do this ... or even if it is possible.

```
select 
    'Dimension' "@type",
    (
        select
            (
                select
                    'X102' "TransactionType",
                    convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) "Transfer/TransferDate",
                    convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) "Transfer/TransferTime"
                for xml path (''), type
            ) "TransactionInformation"
        for xml path (''), type
    )
for xml path ('DimensionImport'), type
```

**Gives me...**

```
<DimensionImport type="Dimension">
    <TransactionInformation>
        <TransactionType>X102</TransactionType>
        <Transfer>
            <TransferDate>21.01.2010</TransferDate>
            <TransferTime>15:46:36</TransferTime>
        </Transfer>
    </TransactionInformation>
</DimensionImport>
```

**I'm wanting...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<DimensionImport type="Dimension">
    <TransactionInformation>
        <TransactionType>X102</TransactionType>
        <Transfer>
            <TransferDate>21.01.2010</TransferDate>
            <TransferTime>15:46:36</TransferTime>
        </Transfer>
    </TransactionInformation>
</DimensionImport>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to lend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add xml encoding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> to xml Output in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002403/how-to-add-xml-encoding-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8-to-xml-output-in)

Comment: I think that would be the other way around. I asked my question first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.  The data type is not returned as an XML datatype, but I can deal with that I guess.

```
select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>' +
(
    select 
        'Dimension' "@type",
        (
            select
                (
                    select
                        'X102' "TransactionType",
                        convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) "Transfer/TransferDate",
                        convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) "Transfer/TransferTime"
                    for xml path (''), type
                )
            for xml path ('TransactionInformation'), type
        ),
        (
            ... queried up data here ...
        )
    for xml path ('DimensionImport')
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's messy, but you could just concatenate it on the front...

```
SELECT '<? xml...>' + 
(select 
    'Dimension' "@type",
    (
        select
            (
                select
                    'X102' "TransactionType",
                    convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) "Transfer/TransferDate",
                    convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) "Transfer/TransferTime"
                for xml path (''), type
            ) "TransactionInformation"
        for xml path (''), type
    )
for xml path ('DimensionImport'), type)
```

Comment: Alas, that did not work.

Error returned:
The data types varchar and xml are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: Yes... if you remove your 'type', and then cast the whole result as xml, that'll help. Like this: `SELECT cast('<? xml...>' + (select 'Dimension' as [@type]....for xml path('DimensionImport')) as xml)

Comment: Hmmm ... it **runs** if I remove the character encoding in the xml declaration, but not if I have it in there.  With the character encoding in the declaration I get this error "XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding".  When I remove the character encoding it **runs**, but I still do not have the xml declaration appended to the xml.  It only shows the original xml.  Ugh!!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>' + 
       (your whole upper select here)
```

Comment: Error returned:
The data types varchar and xml are incompatible in the add operator.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is what I found in [SQL Server Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107(SQL.90).aspx):

The XML declaration PI in an instance is not preserved when the instance is stored in the database. For example:

```
Copy Code CREATE TABLE T1 (Col1 int primary key, Col2 xml)
GO
INSERT INTO T1 values (1, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?><doc></doc>')
GO
SELECT Col2
FROM T1
```

The result is `<doc/>`.

The only workaround is to return the XML as a varchar(max) type:

```
select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>'
+
cast( (
select 
    'Dimension' "@type",
    (
        select
            (
                select
                    'X102' "TransactionType",
                    convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) "Transfer/TransferDate",
                    convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) "Transfer/TransferTime"
                for xml path (''), type
            ) "TransactionInformation"
        for xml path (''), type
    )
for xml path ('DimensionImport'), type) as varchar(max))
```

Comment: That is basically what I ended up doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In 2008 R2 from EM, if you open "Save as" and expand "Save" button, then you can save witch encoding, after that, the xml declaration is added automatically.

Hope it helps.
Regards.