# SQL Server: Nesting Elements with FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Struggling to write query which can generate nested elements in XML. Can anyone help

INPUT:

```
SELECT EmpName AS [Name],
       EmpDOB       AS [Birthdate],
       EmpSalary        AS [WageAmount],
    Add1    AS [Address1],
    Add2    AS [Address2],
    Mobile  AS [Mobile]
FROM   Employee
FOR XML PATH
```

OUTPUT: (this has additional info as a nested element)

```
<Employee>
<Name>Conrad</Name>
<Birthdate>14-oct-76</BirthDate>
<WageAmount>10000</WageAmount>
<AdditionalInfo>
    <Address1>Washington DC</Address1>
    <Address2>DC</Address2>
    <Mobile>989898989</Mobile>
</AdditionalInfo>
</Employee>
```

Comment: See new answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way in this case is to just specify the path in your column alias with a forward slash delimiter:

```
SELECT EmpName AS [Name],
       EmpDOB AS [Birthdate],
       EmpSalary AS [WageAmount],
       Add1 AS [AdditionalInfo/Address1],
       Add2 AS [AdditionalInfo/Address2],
       Mobile AS [AdditionalInfo/Mobile]
FROM   Employee
FOR XML PATH ('Employee')
```

You can also do it with sub-queries that return XML in the select columns.  Something like this:

```
SELECT EmpName AS [Name],
       EmpDOB AS [Birthdate],
       EmpSalary AS [WageAmount],
       (select
           Add1 AS [AdditionalInfo/Address1],
           Add2 AS [AdditionalInfo/Address2],
           Mobile AS [AdditionalInfo/Mobile]
        from Employee EmpAddInfo
        where EmpAddInfo.EmployeeID=Employee.EmployeeID
        FOR XML PATH('AdditionalInfo'), TYPE 
        )
FROM Employee
FOR XML PATH ('Employee')
```

It's silly to do it this way in your case because the fields are all in the same table, but you would do something like this way if you had a detail table to join to.

Comment: You can add the root node by including it's name in the FOR XML PATH statement.  I added it to the answer.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: String concatenation.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002403/how-to-add-xml-encoding-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8-to-xml-output-in

Answer (score 1):

For this task simple `path` mode is not enough and we need more elaborate `explicit` mode. It is rather tricky but gives you maximum flexibility in xml formatting. Detail description is available on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx) site. Here is a query for current question.

```
declare @emp table(--test table
        EmpId int not null identity(1,1),
        EmpName varchar(50),
        EmpDOB datetime,
        EmpSalary money,
        Add1 varchar(50),
        Add2 varchar(50),
        Mobile varchar(20)
        )
--Add some data
insert @emp values
('Conrad','1976-10-14',10000,'Washington DC','DC','989898989'),
('Alex','1966-10-14',15000,'New York','NY','989898988')
-- prepare query 
SELECT 1    Tag, --mandatory field and level 
       0 Parent, --2nd field must be Parent 
       null [Employees!1!EmpID],  --get from 1st level
       NULL [Employee!2!Name!element],  --from 2nd level
       NULL [Employee!2!Birthdate!element],
       null [Employee!2!WageAmount!element],   
       null [AdditionalInfo!3!Address1!element],--from 3rd level
       null [AdditionalInfo!3!Address2!element],
       null [AdditionalInfo!3!Mobile!element]
FROM   @emp
union
SELECT 2    Tag,  --2nd level
       1    Parent, --refer to 1st level 
       EmpId [Employees!1!EmpID],  --all we need on this level
       EmpName [Employee!2!Name!element],  
       EmpDOB [Employee!2!Birthdate!element],
       EmpSalary [Employee!2!WageAmount!element],   
       null [AdditionalInfo!3!Address1!element]  ,
       null [AdditionalInfo!3!Address2!element]  ,
       null [AdditionalInfo!3!MObile!element]
FROM   @emp
union
SELECT 3    Tag,  --3rd level
       2 Parent,  --include into 2nd level
       EmpId [Employees!1],  
       NULL [Employee!2!Name!element],  
       NULL [Employee!2!Birthdate!element],
       null [Employee!2!WageAmount!element],   
       Add1 [AdditionalInfo!3!Address1!element]  ,
       Add2 [AdditionalInfo!3!Address2!element]  ,
       Mobile [AdditionalInfo!3!MObile!element]
FROM   @emp
order by [Employees!1!EmpID]
for xml explicit --This is explicit mode
```

And test result:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Conrad</Name>
    <Birthdate>1976-10-14T00:00:00</Birthdate>
    <WageAmount>10000.0000</WageAmount>
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Address1>Washington DC</Address1>
      <Address2>DC</Address2>
      <Mobile>989898989</Mobile>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Alex</Name>
    <Birthdate>1966-10-14T00:00:00</Birthdate>
    <WageAmount>15000.0000</WageAmount>
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <Address1>New York</Address1>
      <Address2>NY</Address2>
      <Mobile>989898988</Mobile>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

This is what we need.

Comment: insert @emp values
('Conrad','1976-10-14',10000,'Washington DC','DC','989898989'),
('Alex','1966-10-14',15000,'New York','NY','989898988')

Comment: if i can get 2 records for CONRAD ... in second he changed his address.... now under additionalinfo... i want to display both the address how to make this possible. And thanks for excellent suggestions... on how to have more control over XML

Comment: Very simple. Change EmpId on 2nd and 3rd level to EmpName.